# Domain admin accounts can do less than domain administrator account

Tags: active-directory, security

On a Windows 2008R2 server, a domain admin account has lesser rights than the domain administrator account.  For example, the domain admin account can't install a service or create a file on the root of C:drive.  I've checked that the domain admin group is a member of the local administrator group.

Any ideas on why this is happening?  We're trying to disable the domain administrator account.

Comment: UAC?  Try running as administrator.

Comment: Can you clarify: Do you mean a member of the Domain Admins group versus the domain Administrator user account?

Comment: @joeqwerty - yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to log-off / log-on ? If you just changed groups you'll need this to validate the changes. However as the [Default local groups](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771990.aspx)'page suggest, the Domain Admins group should be added automatically to the local Administrators group, thus be able to manipulate services, especially if this is not a new setup.

Then, I would check if there's not already specific restricting setup in the [Local Security Policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd277395.aspx) for the Domain Admins group.

Eventually; I would check the permissions on the C: folder, you never know...